# Calculating a parametrized maximum, as a function of the parameter

Tags: functions

Suppose I have the following maximization problem:

```
Maximize[{x^2-a,0<=x<=a},{x}]
```

The result is a function of $a$:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to extract this function of $a$. I tried:

```
mm[a_] := Out[34][[1]]
```

but this did not work. For example, mm[1] returns:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What is the correct way of defining this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things you need to be aware of and I advise to read the [most common pitfalls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) post. Learn the difference between `:=` and `=` and don't use things like `Out` in a definition. That definitely bites you at some point.

That being said, please look at the following solution:

```
{res, val} = Maximize[{x^2 - a, 0 <= x <= a}, {x}];
mm[a_] = res;
mm[4]
```

Comment: I see. So the problem was just that I used := instead of =.